# Is there any value in leaving Tubbs to enjoy his meal after he ate it?

Tags: neko-atsume

Is there any value in not replacing the food just eaten by Tubbs until he departs by himself?
[image: "Siesta"]
Will he give me more fish if I leave him alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Tubbs' entry on the [Neko Atsume unofficial wiki](http://nekoatsume.wikia.com/wiki/Tubbs):

> Tubbs will leave eventually, or immediately should the player replace the Food. However, the player will be rewarded with more Fish or Gold Fish if Tubbs leaves on its own.

I have also experienced this behavior in my own personal playthrough. Ultimately, I would conclude that one *does* get more fish if the food is left alone until Tubbs departs.